# pgSQL: return all results, but possibly not one result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to select everything in a table where the `id` column is not a particular value. However, is it possible to have that particular value be optional, and in that case return all the results.

It seems like `case` might be what I want, but it's not working for me. What I've tried

```
WHERE id != ''
```

or

```
WHERE id (SELECT CASE WHEN $id IS NULL THEN '')
                            ^^ $id could be, say, 10 or NULL
```

is just the incorrect syntax. How can I make this query? Thanks much.

Comment: Under what conditions do you want to show the particular value of `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
WHERE (id != v_id OR v_id IS NULL)
```

It will return all rows where `id != v_id` if `v_id` is not null

Or return all rows if `v_id` is null

Answer (score 1):

When you want any id then pass `$id` as empty or null. Otherwise pass the real id. Doing it the empty way:

```
where (id = $id or $id = '')
```

Using null:

```
where (id = $id or $id is null)
```